# Image with text on the left side HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do manually this kind of design

[image]

Now I have this code to make it look like it.

```
   <div class="container">
            <div class="jet-container">
                <div class="jet-section">
                    <img src="{{ asset('public/images/courses.png') }}" alt="">
                    <p>PROFESSIONAL AND OWNER</p>
                    <h3>PILOTS</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="jet-section">2</div>
                <div class="jet-section">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Something like they are sticked together the `text` and the `image`

whether the screen size are desktop, tablet, mobile mode.

The design will stay the same.

Just a newbie here

Comment: make `.jet-section` relative position, but `.jet-section p` absolute. I would remove h3 and move it inside the paragraph as a span or em, display block;

Comment: I'll try to do it.